# What are transported cargo limits for every vehicle?

Tags: death-stranding

In-game vehicles have some limit on how much cargo one can put into them - it's either in number of packages or in total weight. I cannot find any way to predict load in game - I can put packages into my truck until I suddenly cannot.

What are these exact limits for every vehicle? How they are different for different vehicle levels and for different modifications (regular vs long range vs whatever other types are present)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a proof for that, only my personal experience.

- Regular bike: 2 XL containers or combination of smaller ones up to 2L
  pieces
- MOLE truck: equivalent of 6XL containers in the trunk and equivalent
  of 2L containers from your back on the driver's seat
- BRIDGES truck: equivalent of 20XL containers in the trunk and
  equivalent of 2L containers from your back on the driver's seat
- Floating cart: equivalent of 6XL containers, up to 300 kg (lvl1) or
  600 kg (lvl2)

Comment: So trucks don't have weight limit only volume limit, right? What about long range and  armored versions?

Comment: I don't know for sure. Once I loaded about 1700 KG of metals, alloys and ceramics, and it went just fine. It was long-range version. In their description there's no mentions of changes in load capacity. I think it just reduces its speed slightly

Answer (score 2):

Incomplete answer:

When you're loading items from a cargo terminal with a vehicle nearby, there's a weight limit display at the bottom. It turns red if the total amount of cargo you've selected exceeds the capacity of you + the vehicle. Of course, this doesn't help if you're loading the vehicle from the field.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest things you can do with a truck is to look at its backside.  You will find there is a panel of lights on it (towards the right side), the more of which turn on as the truck's capacity is used up.  Load up too much and the lights will turn red.  A screenshot can be found, for example, [in this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DeathStranding/comments/dv6kq3/check_your_trucks_capacity_for_cargo_using_the/).

From the same thread, one user posts the following information about the Bridges trucks:

> I've done the leg work and I can tell you that the maximum cargo capacity for that truck is 168 Small cargo. 84 Medium, 42 Large or 21 Extra Large. ... TL;DR - All [Bridges] trucks have same cargo space.

Which seems consistent with Alien's existing answer, give or take one XL.